# Bootstrap NavBar Collapse Menu Change Size based on Screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not really good with css, somehow I managed to modify my navbar to make the collapsible button appear no matter how small or big the screen size is by adding this on my Site.css:

```
@media (max-width: 4000px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .navbar-text {
        float: none;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
    /* since 3.1.0 */
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
        display: block!important;
    }
    .collapsing {
        overflow: hidden!important;
    }
    .navbar-form {
    width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Now my navbar behaves the way I want it to except for 1 thing:
[image]

When I click the collapsible button, the drop down menu background takes all the space of the screen. What I want is when user is on desktop, the collapsible menu takes a specific width only. What should I change in my css file? This is my desired output (when using desktop ONLY): 
[image]

Comment: please can you post your html code OR fiddle?

Comment: Check that you don't have an unclosed element. It looks like this might be the case. If not, please put the html and css in a jsfiddle. thanks